# Why does the shading looks bad on this subdivided and reinforced pillar?

Tags: shaders, edges, subdivision-surface

I am modeling a Nissan Z GT500 and I got this weird shading artifacts when I added subdivision surface modifier and wanted to add reinforcing edges/vertices:

[image]

I think it would need another reinforcing edge but I'm not sure.

I included the .blend file if anyone wants to take a closer look:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SL9-5o73_eClezarKP5Slb0IJ3wlA5s3/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an inner face, therefore this bad shading, remove it:

[image]

Then you'll have to add this edge loop:

[image]

Comment: Wow how could I miss that, I thought I removed every inner face, might have missed it when I joined the two meshes together

Thank you moonboots!